# MS Azure/Code-First: Login failed for user

Tags: azure, ef-code-first, azure-sql-database

I want to deploy my ASP.NET application to MS Azure (and SQL Azure). The application is using code-first.

After publishing my application and calling the corresponding URL I receive an error message saying:

> Login failed for user 'myUserName'. This session has been assigned a tracing
>   ID of '8beaff1c-629f-45b3-991b-228425bc30a4'.Provide this tracing ID
>   to customer support when you need assistance.

I'm pretty sure this is due to connection strings in my config files.

Here is the relevant extract from my web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbContext" 
         connectionString="server(local)\SQLEXPRESS;database=myDB;integrated security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And here is the corresponding web.release.config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Server=tcp:xt1rnwvt89.database.windows.net;Database=myDB;User ID=myUserName@xt1rnwvt89;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    <add name="dbContext" connectionString="Server=tcp:xt1rnwvt89.database.windows.net,1433;Database=myDB;User ID=myUserName@xt1rnwvt89;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

I'm not sure if I need both the `ApplicationServices` and `dbContext` settings...?

Of course the credentials given above are anonymized. But the real credentials should be correct, because I can successfully connect to my Azure database with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

I already checked several documentations and tutorials like https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-app-with-sql-azure/, but I couldn't find a solution yet. Everything seems to be ok.

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the connectionstring I use:

```
<add name="dbContext" connectionString="Server=tcp:xxxxxxxx.database.windows.net;Database=xxxxxxxx;User ID=xxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxxx;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Also make you sure set the correct firewall settings:

- When deployed you should have the '*Allow other Windows Azure Services to access this server.*' option checked.
- When connecting from another network make sure to add that IP to the firewall rules otherwhise you will have a connection denied.

If you want to make sure you use the correct connection you can ask the correct one from the management portal. Just click your databasename on the left and then you can see the connection string on the right panel.

*Edit*
Also when using Code First make sure the database doesn't already exist because the database drop won't work.

Comment: Hi Kevin, looks like our connection strings are pretty much the same. Firewall settings exist (one for "other Windows Azure Services" and one for my personal IP - otherwise I could not connect with MSSMS, right?). And yes, I copied the connection string right from the portal.

Comment: No, the database does not exist already. Code-First is supposed to create it.

Comment: Try placing the official connectionstring in your web.config as well and try to run locally and see if the database is created on the Azure platform.

Comment: Yes, THAT worked. I replaced server(local)\SQLEXPRESS;database=myDB;integrated security=true in my local web.config with Server=tcp:xt1rnwvt89.database.windows.net,1433;Database=myDB;User ID=myUserName@xt1rnwvt89;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;. The database was created in Azure!

Comment: Now I wonder if anything is wrong about my web.release.config. Do you think I need providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" in the web.release.config too? Just checking...but it takes about 10min to publish a new package.

Comment: Could it be you deployed with the wrong build configuration? If you want it to use the web.release.config then you need to put the build configuration on release when you publish/package.

Comment: Ja, thanks for that suggestion too. But I already checked this.

Comment: About the providerName, only one way to find out ;)

Comment: Just another idea: my whole db related code is located in a library project (DLL). So not in the ASP.NET web project. Maybe the DLL does not pick up the right connection string?

Comment: Doesn't really sound like it should give a problem. It's working locally so. The problem lays with the config file. Just use the working connectionstring in the web.release and try it :

Comment: Sorry, the new deployment took forever. But it seems to work now. The database has been created (again). However, now I'm getting errors while trying to connect to the SQL Server session database. But I guess I will be able to figure this out too...after another 100 deployments ;-) Thanks so much for your help, Kevin!!!

Comment: Sometimes the node your db is on fails and your db is failed over to a different node which causes brief unavailabilty (I believe the SLA in SQLAzure TOS is 30secs), so make sure you have a retry logic

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue (Login failed for user 'myUserName) trying to set up the connection between my webmatrix azure web app to my azure sql database.

Had no problem connecting into the azure sql database using sql server management studio. So I knew that my username and password were ok.

I tried linking the web app to the sql database in the dashboard as suggested however this does not work for me. Spent a long time messing with connection strings in my web.config file. Trying stuff and uploading the new files to test.

Then discovered that the connection string is stored in the web app configuration page in the azure portal dashboard. It turns out that my password still had the curly braces around it in the connection string (as illustrated in the default suggested string). I must have entered it like that at some point. Removing the curly braces solved the issue.

This is another option to try if anyone else is having problems.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. When using the connection strings in App Services, it's for when you deploy your app. However, to test locally you need that connection string in your web.config. They do different things, but are easy to get confused.

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I would share this. I had the same issue and adding the db as a linked resource in the management portal, **cloud service > dashboard > add linked resource**, solved it for me. I was getting the login failed for user error for HOURS before I figured this out!!

Comment: There is a tab now called "Linked Resources". Or at the bottom of the Dashboard tab, there is an area called "linked resources" with a button "Manage Linked Resources ->"

Comment: i had a dollar sign in connection sting. F*** you MS, you told me yourself to put it there

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was something stupid that I did . . . I was passing the connection string in using a command prompt, and my password had a % sign as part of it.  When using a command prompt, % is used to indicate command line arguments, so the command interpreter simply dropped the % sign and I couldn't connect anymore.

The fix?  Escape the % sign.

Not working:
Password=PasswordWithPercent%

Working
Password=PasswordWithPercent%%

Hurrah!

Answer (score 0):

I hit a similar problem running the command from Visual Studio's package manager. I had to put single quotes around the connection string because the password had a $ sign in it. With double quotes it tries to process a variable in there.